# How to create array of unique object list in Swift

Tags: swift, nsset

How can we create unique object list in Swift language like `NSSet` & `NSMutableSet` in Objective-C.

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? Swift has NSArray equivalents and NSDictionary equivalents, maybe it has sets too but they're simply not documented?

Comment: People downvote swift questions without considering that they might not be documented yet.

Comment: Swift 1.2 adds a `Set` type.

Comment: …and I guess I should also say that Swift 1.2 is available in the Xcode 6.3 beta.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

As of Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3 beta), Swift has a native set type.
From the release notes:

> A new `Set` data structure is included which provides a generic
>   collection of unique elements, with full value semantics. It bridges
>   with `NSSet`, providing functionality analogous to `Array` and `Dictionary`.

Here are some simple usage examples:

```
// Create set from array literal:
var set = Set([1, 2, 3, 2, 1])

// Add single elements:
set.insert(4)
set.insert(3)

// Add multiple elements:
set.unionInPlace([ 4, 5, 6 ])
// Swift 3: set.formUnion([ 4, 5, 6 ])

// Remove single element:
set.remove(2)

// Remove multiple elements:
set.subtractInPlace([ 6, 7 ])
// Swift 3: set.subtract([ 6, 7 ])

print(set) // [5, 3, 1, 4]

// Test membership:
if set.contains(5) {
    print("yes")
}
```

but there are far more methods available.

**Update:** Sets are now also documented in the ["Collection Types"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) chapter of  the Swift documentation.

Comment: Yea for now just use `NSMutableSet` with `addObject`, `removeObject`, and `allObject` that pretty much does it. The native `Set` would be a nice thing to have later.

Answer (score 15):

You can use any Objective-C class in Swift:

```
var set = NSMutableSet()
set.addObject(foo)
```

Comment: You can, but if you try to put a Swift object in it it'll complain that it doesn't extend `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 10):

Swift has no concept of sets. Using `NSMutableSet` in Swift might be slower than using a `Dictionary` that holds dummy values. You could do this :

```
var mySet: Dictionary<String, Boolean> = [:]
mySet["something"]= 1
```

Then just iterate over the keys.

Comment: Booleans in Swift are different than numbers. You probably meant true instead of 1.

Comment: @KPM You're thinking of the Bool struct; Boolean is a typealias for UInt8 in Swift.

Comment: IMO use Bool instead of Boolean. Bool is a swift data type and takes values true / false which can be stored in dictionaries

Answer (score 9):

I've built an extensive `Set` type similar to the built-in `Array` and `Dictionary` - here are blog posts one and two and a GitHub repository:

- [Creating a Set Type in Swift](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/08/creating-a-set-type-in-swift/)
- [Set Type Follow-up](http://natecook.com/blog/2014/08/set-type-follow-up/)
- [SwiftSets on GitHub](https://github.com/natecook1000/SwiftSets)

Answer (score 7):

```
extension Array where Element: Hashable {
    var setValue: Set<Element> {
        return Set<Element>(self)
    }
}

let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,0,9,8,7]
let uniqueNumbers = numbers.setValue    // {0, 2, 4, 9, 5, 6, 7, 3, 1, 8}

let names = ["John","Mary","Steve","Mary"]
let uniqueNames = names.setValue    // {"John", "Mary", "Steve"}
```

Answer (score 4):

I thought a struct with an internal Dictionary would be the way to go. I have only just started using it, so it’s not complete and I have no idea on performance yet.

```
struct Set<T : Hashable>
{
    var _items : Dictionary<T, Bool> = [:]

    mutating func add(newItem : T) {
        _items[newItem] = true
    }

    mutating func remove(newItem : T) {
        _items[newItem] = nil
    }

    func contains(item: T) -> Bool {
        if _items.indexForKey(item) != nil { return true } else { return false }
    }

    var items : [T] { get { return [T](_items.keys) } }
    var count : Int { get { return _items.count } }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually can create a Set object pretty easy (in contradiction to GoZoner, there is a built in contains method):

```
class Set<T : Equatable> {
    var items : T[] = []

    func add(item : T) {
        if !contains(items, {$0 == item}) {
            items += item
        }
    }
}
```

and you maybe even want to declare a custom operator:

```
@assignment @infix func += <T : Equatable> (inout set : Set<T>, items : T[]) -> Set<T> {
    for item in items {
        set.add(item)
    }
    return set
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted, it's not very efficient but it's definitely a viable solution for small sets.

Answer (score 2):

Always in such a case the critical factor is how to compare objects and what types of objects go into the Set.  Using a Swift Dictionary, where the Set objects are the dictionary keys, could be a problem based on the restrictions on the key type (String, Int, Double, Bool, valueless Enumerations or hashable).

**If you can define a hash function** on your object type then you can use a Dictionary.  **If the objects are orderable**, then you could define a Tree.  **If the objects are only comparable with `==`** then you'll need to iterate over the set elements to detect a preexisting object.

```
// When T is only Equatable
class Set<T: Equatable> {
  var items = Array<T>()

  func hasItem (that: T) {
   // No builtin Array method of hasItem... 
   //   because comparison is undefined in builtin Array   
   for this: T in items {
     if (this == that) {
       return true
     }
   }
   return false
  }

  func insert (that: T) {
    if (!hasItem (that))
      items.append (that)
  }
}
```

The above is an example of building a Swift `Set`; the example used objects that are only `Equatable` - which, while a common case, doesn't necessarily lead to an efficient `Set` implementations (O(N) search complexity - the above is an example).

Comment: I think Equatable would be more correct than Comparable. Equatable is defined as `protocol Equatable {
    func ==(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}` while Comparable is `protocol Comparable : Equatable {
    func <=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    func >=(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
    func >(lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool
}`

Answer (score 1):

So I think creating a Set with an array is a terrible idea - O(n) is the time complexity of that set.

I have put together a nice Set that uses a dictionary: https://github.com/evilpenguin/Swift-Stuff/blob/master/Set.swift

Comment: Although for few elements an array is likely much faster. Cocoa collection classes often chose to return different subclasses of NSArray, NSSet etc depending on number of elements you used.

Comment: The set implementation doesn't take into account hash collisions, where two objects create the same hash even though they are not identical.  I believe a fully fledged implementation has to take into account equality as well as hash.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to solve this problem.

```
public func removeDuplicates<C: ExtensibleCollectionType where C.Generator.Element : Equatable>(aCollection: C) -> C {
    var container = C()

    for element in aCollection {
        if !contains(container, element) {
            container.append(element)
        }
    }

    return container
}
```

To use it, just pass an array which contains duplicate elements to this function. And then it will return a uniqueness-guaranteed array.

You also can pass a `Dictionary`, `String` or anything conforms to `ExtensibleCollectionType` protocol if you like.

Comment: Note that this implementation is keeping the first occurence of each duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Special case for classes derived from NSObject

given that default Equitable (& Hashable) conformance in NSObject is basically trash you'd better make sure you provide a proper

```
static func == (lhs: YourClassDerivedFromNSObject, rhs: YourClassDerivedFromNSObject) -> Bool {
```

implementation lest you want plucking the duplicates inserted into
Set