# What is a equivalent of HashSet Java in Swift?

Tags: java, swift

I have specific logic in Java that uses `HashSet<String>`. Set collection contains only unique items.

For example:

```
Set<String> mySets = new HashSet<String>();
mySets.add("a");
mySets.add("a");
mySets.add("b");
mySets.add("a");
```

I get: `["a","b"]`.

What is equivalent  collection in Swift?

Thanks,

Comment: this page https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html talks about arrays and  dictionary. Since Dictionary keys are unique, you could use a dummy value as value and work with keys only (like current HashSet implementation of Java)

Comment: Swift 1.2 has a native Set type now, compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/28426765/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR thank you, wait for release

Answer (score 30):

The Swift to Java's `HashSet` is `Set`.

Example:

```
var s = Set<Character>()
s.insert("a")
s.insert("a")
s.insert("b")
s.insert("a")
print("s: \(s)")
```

output:

```
s: ["b", "a"]
```

[Official docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID484)