# Set<NSObject>' does not have a member named 'allObjects'

Tags: swift, nsset

With the original swift I could turn an NSSet (e.g. of Strings) into a typed array with the following syntax:

```
var stringArray = exampleSet.allObjects as [String]
```

With the new update I am getting the above error.  What is the best way now to convert the Set into an array?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It looks as if your `exampleSet` is not an `NSSet` but a native
Swift `Set` which was introduced with Swift 1.2 (compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/28426765/1187415).

In that case you can convert it to an array simply with

```
let array = Array(exampleSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like 'set' is a keyword.  Try using a different variable name

Comment: this was just an example, not actually the variable name, ive changed the question - sorry for confusion