# Optimize Slow Nested Loop

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have a loop that runs slowly. Is there a more efficient way of checking two arrays against each other in swift.

```
for photo in foodPhotos {
    for restaurant in self.restaurants {
        if (restaurant.objectId == photo.objectId){
            self.detailsForFoodPhotos.append(restaurant) // create array of ordered restaurants
            break // break if we find the matching restaurant
        }
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

For each element, the loop finds the `objectId` in the first array ( `foodPhotos`) that matches the `objectId` of an element in the second array (`restaurants`).

If the `objectIds` match, save the `restaurants` element in `detailsForFoodPhotos`. Continue until all `foodPhotos` have been checked.

#### Example:

Array of Photos: `foodPhotos`:

```
[ photo1, photo2, photo3 ]
```

Array of Restaurants `restaurants`:

```
[ restaurant1, restaurant2, restaurant3, restaurant4, restaurant3 ]
```

The loop checks which `photo.objectID` matches `restaurant.objectID`. Then creates a new array with the matching restaurants.

Output Array: `detailsForFoodPhotos`

```
[ restaurant3, restaurant1, restaurant2 ] 
// photo1.objectID == restaurant3.objectID
// photo2.objectID == restaurant1.objectID
// photo3.objectID == restaurant2.objectID
```

Comment: "The loop checks if the `objectId` of each element in the first array: `foodPhotoRestaurantPFObjects` matches the second array" How an `objectId` match an _array_? Do you mean it is sufficient if the `objectID` is _in_ the array?

Comment: store the objectIds of array `foodPhotoRestaurantPFObjects` in a set. that way, you won't need to iterate it again, and you are down to O(n) from O(n^2). i don't know the exact equivalent and syntax of `HashSet` in Swift but you can get help from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044190/how-to-create-array-of-unique-object-list-in-swift

Comment: Are `objectID` values unique?

Comment: @matt yes each `foodPhotoRestaurantPFObjects` has a unique `objectID`. But `restaurantPFObjects` may contain duplicates. Basically I want to remove the duplicates and match the order.

Comment: "Basically I want to remove the duplicates and match the order." Oh, really???? That's new information (to me). Then what do you need `foodPhotoRestaurantPFObjects` for? Why isn't it sufficient to remove the duplicates from `restaurantPFObjects`? (And "match the order" of what, exactly?) (And one more question: are duplicate `restaurantPFObjects` absolutely duplicates, or different except for their object IDs?)

Comment: Somehow the business logic totally masks the programming logic. After looking at the code and explanation for some time, I still don't understand what is or should be going on here.

Comment: may I ask why the order of the foodPhotoRestauraunt objects should not change?

Comment: @JoshHamet Because the `foodPhoto` array is ordered based on number of votes.

Comment: I don't see any use for the outer break condition, and the inner loop would be left to a find method on the array (if I understand that correctly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still think my other answer is the way to go. However, you haven't accepted it, and you've provided some actual data input and desired output, so here's a solution that produces it:

```
struct Photo {
    let objectID : Int
}
struct Restaurant {
    let objectID : Int
}

let foodPhotos = [Photo(objectID:1), Photo(objectID:2), Photo(objectID:3)]
let restaurants = [Restaurant(objectID:3), Restaurant(objectID:1), Restaurant(objectID:2)]
var d = [Int:Int]()
for (ix,r) in restaurants.enumerate() {
    d[r.objectID] = ix
}
var detailsForFoodPhotos = [Restaurant]()
for p in foodPhotos {
    if let ix = d[p.objectID] {
        detailsForFoodPhotos.append(restaurants[ix])
    }
}
// Now I'll prove that it worked
print(foodPhotos)
// [Photo(objectID: 1), Photo(objectID: 2), Photo(objectID: 3)]
print(restaurants)
// [Restaurant(objectID: 3), Restaurant(objectID: 1), Restaurant(objectID: 2)]
print(detailsForFoodPhotos)
// [Restaurant(objectID: 1), Restaurant(objectID: 2), Restaurant(objectID: 3)]
```

That requires just two simple loops; both are very fast. The key to the solution is the generation of an intermediate lookup table (dictionary), `d`, that hashes on the `objectID` to index into the second array.

Answer (score -1):

you can use a dictionary to remove inner loop. Just index with element.objectId in the dictionary. If it is nil then not present else it is present. if you need code I can provide.

Comment: Can anyone suggest: why it is down voted. Is not the idea same as accepted answer? Thanks.