# iOS Swift 2 - Check if function already in array

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

This is my array for function

```
var funcArray = Array<() -> Void>()
```

To the array I append closure functions which comes as a parameter

```
func someFunc(completition: (() -> Void)?){
// ...
     if let callback = completition {
         funcArray.append(callback)
     }
// ...
}
```

How can I check if the array already contains the function before appending it to the array ?

Comment: [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044190/how-to-create-array-of-unique-object-list-in-swift) is what you are looking for i guess.

Comment: If I remember correctly, you *cannot* compare closures.