# How set, append, insert new value in NSSet in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsset

How to add dynamic value in NSSet variable?

```
var productID: NSSet = NSSet(objects: "com.b100bios")
```

append, add new value in productID "new 1","new 2", "new 3" in Swift.

expected result: productID = {("com.b100bios","new 1","new 2", "new 3")}

Comment: Why not use a proper Swift `Set` instead of `NSSet`?

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24044190/how-to-create-array-of-unique-object-list-in-swift